# Make params required in a rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that accepts three params, `title`, `users` and `project_type`. I want to make all the params required

I have seen people do things like

```
           def project_params
                params.require(:title,:project_type, :users)
                        .permit(:title, :project_type, :users)
            end
```

And then do `Project.new(project_params)`, but I need to work a little with the params first. How can I make this possible?

I make a post request in postman like this:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
            def create
                    admins = params[:admins]
                    users = get_user_array()

                    project_type = ProjectCategory.find_by(name: params[:project_type])

                        project = Project.new(
                            title: params[:title], 
                            project_category: project_type, 
                            project_users: users)

                        if project.save
                            render json: {data:project}, status: :ok
                        else
                            render json: {data:project.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
                        end
            end

            ...

        end
    end
end
```

```
{
    "title": "Tennis",
    "project_type": "Sports",
    "users": [{"name": "john Dow", "email": "johnDoe@gmail.com"}],
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are only getting ```project_type``` and ```title``` as params. Isn't the params[:project_type] what you want to save in your project_category field? Also, how does your ```get_user_array()```works?

Comment: yes, but a got to proccess params[:project_type] before creating the project. `get_user_array()` just gives an array of users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that you are using `ActionController::Parameters#require` wrong. Its not meant to validate that the all the required attributes are present - thats what [model validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) are for. Rather you should just use `params.require` to ensure that the general structure of the parameters is processable.

For example if you used the rails scaffold you would get the following whitelist:

```
params.require(:project)
      .permit(:title, :project_type)
```

This is because there is no point in continuing execution if the `project` key is missing from the params hash since this would give you an empty hash or nil.

`ActionController::Parameters#require` will raise a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error which will return a `400 - Bad Request` response which is the wrong response code for what you are doing. You also should not use exceptions for normal application flow. A missing attribute is not an exceptional event.

Instead if you want to use a flat params hash you should whitelist it with:

```
def project_params
  params.permit(:title, :project_type, users: [:name, :email])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you don't have to get anything from the frontend to run `get_user_array()`, you could only allow and require `title` and `project_type`.

```rb
def create
  users = get_user_array()
  project = Project.new(project_params)
  project.users = users
  if project.save
    render json: {data:project}, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {data:project.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :project_type).tap do |project_params|
    project_params.require(:title, :project_type)
  end
end
```

If you need to process something before creating the project, you can do this:

```rb
  project_category = ProjectCategory.find_by(name: project.project_type)
```